# Vulnerability testing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have been involved in test based development on ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebAPI using NMock unit test, however most of the unit tests that I write revolve around testing functionality.

**From the point of view of Unit Testing :**

Are there any frameworks to test vulnerability of access points Actions on Controllers
(or any other components)

**From the point of view automated/manual QA testing**

Are there any (prefer open source) **tools** for testing vulnerability of a website built on ASP.NET MVC , manual or automatic , which can be used for Quality Assurance ?

Comment: This is a great question, but I suspect there aren't any. Common site vulnerabilities depend on so many factors. For example, your vulnerability to Cross Site Scripting depends on how many maleable values are left un-encoded. No tool could trace the origin of your variables (esp not in a mocked environment). Another variable is how many of your pages will run on Secure Socket Layer. None of those pages have as concern about forgery attacks...

Comment: Thanks. I was also interested in knowing if there were any open source testing tools from the point of view of QA testing.

Comment: I would love to know too. Skeptical is very different than uninterested ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would go about testing your ASP.NET MVC application in the same manner as I would test any other web application built on any other platform.

Essentially your attack vectors are the web pages and server(s) hosting the application. Think about it from an attackers point of view. They have no way to see the code in your controllers and models but they can do the following.

- Scan your server(s) for OS version , web server version, db version that may contain vulnerabilities.
- Scan your webpages for vulnerable JavaScript, input forms, query string parameters, etc.
- Attempt to exploit your web application through any discovered vulnerabilities

You can use any number of applications to test your site for xss, csrf, sql injection, etc. A good place to start is OWASP
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page
Get familiar with top 10
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Also check out this SO post regarding open source web vulnerabilities scanners
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995143/open-source-web-site-vulnerability-scanners

Remember that the two main attack vectors will be user input and server configuration.

I would also recommend taking a look at NMap and MetaSploit. Nmap can be used for finding open ports on a server and MetaSploit is a framework for exploiting vulnerabilities.

Comment: After a little more searching, I found Gendarme which might help you with Manual Testing http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme

Answer (score 2):

Well one the biggest areas that you should look at is the ModelBinding, since that usually creates massive vulnerabilities.

For example take a look at this question and see if you can spot the vulnerability:

- [Security vulnerability created by ASP.NET MVC ModelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724899/security-vulnerability-created-by-asp-net-mvc-modelbinder) (SO Question)
- [Can you spot the security implications/vulnerability of a small change to an ASP.NET MVC 3.0+ Model Binder?](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/07/can-you-spot-security.html)