# Security vulnerability created by ASP.NET MVC ModelBinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

as I ask in detail at [Can you spot the security implications/vulnerability of a small change to an ASP.NET MVC 3.0+ Model Binder?](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/07/can-you-spot-security.html) one of the versions of the CartModelBinder class (shown below) allows exploitation via MVC ModelBinding Vulnerability (also called OverPosting)

Can you spot which one?

Ideally you should provide your answer/results/proof using UnitTests :)

**Version 1:** Using DefaultModelBinder and CreateModel

```
public class CartModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private const string sessionKey = "Cart";

    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        // get the Cart from the session
        Cart cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];
        // create the Cart if there wasn't one in the session data
        if (cart == null)
        {
            cart = new Cart();
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = cart;
        }
        // return the cart
        return cart;
    }
}
```

**Version 2:** Using IModelBinder and BindModel

```
public class CartModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private const string sessionKey = "Cart";

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        // get the Cart from the session
        Cart cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];
        // create the Cart if there wasn't one in the session data
        if (cart == null)
        {
            cart = new Cart();
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = cart;
        }
        // return the cart
        return cart;
    }
}
```

**Controller example:**

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
{
    Product product = repository.Products
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

    if (product != null)
    {
        cart.AddItem(product, 1);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
}
```

Comment: The second version only returns carts from the session. The first version can return carts from post data.

Comment: yeah, and that is not a good thing right?

Comment: Yes in this example because the products and maybe the prices can be edited by posting a different cart. Maybe this specific example is contrived but why would you accept a cart as a parameter if you don't want the data to post. That's a lot of obfuscation just to get an item from the session. That's your real error.

Comment: The idea of the original code is that those values should not be edited (in the safe version, they use a server side session variable to hold the cart). You can see all controllers here: https://github.com/o2platform/Fork_SportsStore_ASPNET_MVC/blob/master/SportsStore.WebUI/Controllers/CartController.cs

Comment: Precisely. That should be a field created in the controller constructor instead of as a property on the method.

Answer (score 1):

Your current design can be easily misused like you suggested. A better solution would be to get the cart initially and use that instance.

```
  public class CartController : Controller
  {
        private IProductRepository repository;
        private IOrderProcessor orderProcessor;
        private cart;
        public CartController(IProductRepository repo, IOrderProcessor proc)
        {
            repository = repo;
            orderProcessor = proc;
            cart = Session["Cart"]; // or Cart.Current
        }

        public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

            if (product != null)
            {
                cart.AddItem(product, 1);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }

  }
```